# Share link to posts when using FB.ui

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-wall, fb.ui

I made a small app to FB that is using FB.ui to allow users to share it on their wall. I'd like the shared posts to show "Share" link next to "Comment" and "Like", like on any normal wall post.

Is there any way to do this with FB.ui?

Or is there some other method that would still allow me to define customized image, title, description etc. to the wall post?

My current code:

```
function share(name, description) {
        FB.ui({
            method: 'feed',
            name: name,
            picture: '/img/fb.png',
            link: url,
            caption: '',
            message: '',
            description: description
            }, function() {
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it can be done with `share_open_graph` method. the code should look like this

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'share_open_graph',
    action_type: 'og.shares',
    action_properties: JSON.stringify({
        object : {
           'og:url': 'http://astahdziq.in/', // your url to share
           'og:title': 'Here my custom title',
           'og:description': 'here custom description',
           'og:image': 'http://example.com/link/to/your/image.jpg'
        }
    })
    },
    // callback
    function(response) {
    if (response && !response.error_message) {
        // then get post content
        alert('successfully posted. Status id : '+response.post_id);
    } else {
        alert('Something went error.');
    }
});
```

Comment: I believe this method has been added after this question was asked, but this looks like what I was looking for back then. Thanks.

Comment: i am glad if this can help someone, :)

Answer (score 0):

For [the `share` action](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog),

```
FB.ui({
  method: 'share',
  href: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
}, function(response){});
```

To define customized image, title, description, use [Open Graph Tags](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/web/webmasters) in the head of your page:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://samples.ogp.me/136756249803614" /> 
<meta property="og:title" content="Chocolate Pecan Pie" />
<meta property="og:description" content="This pie is delicious!" /> 
<meta property="og:image" content="https://fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/851565_496755187057665_544240989_n.jpg" />
```

The effect would be:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You have to use the **action** property
see the documentation [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/)

Comment: Thanks, but can you be a bit more specific, how you use the action property to enable a share link? The documentation doesn't mention anything about share links.

Comment: action: [
                { text: 'Game', href: 'http://www.example.com/' }
            ],

Comment: That would just make a link called "Game" that goes to "example.com". What I want to do is create a share link that would allow users to share the post on their own wall, like on normal status updates.

Comment: mmm maybe you should use this new feature released yesterday http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/05/02/action-links--a-new-way-to-interact-with-apps/